# Incorrect "float object is not subscriptable" Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
        for item in element[1]:
                  print(item[0])
                  temp_list.append(item[0])
```

Print gives results:

```
63.0
65.0
70.0
```

Which means I'm not trying to access the subscript of each float, but the entire float.

Then I get error:

```
  File "...", line 126, in extract_data
    print(item[0])
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

???

This error still occurs on the `append` statement if I remove the `print` statement.

`item` is a tuple of (float, string)

Comment: the error means that forth item is float and not a tuple. try to print item, not item[0]

Comment: Obviously at least one item of element[1] is just a float.

Comment: Wow, you guys so smart!  Debug gurus, thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Assuming element looks like this :

```
element = [(63.0, "ez"),(65.0, "zer"),(70.0, "oy")]
```

By doing

```
for item in element[1]:
```

element[1] is your second element in your list, so it is here (65.0, "zer").
So when you browse item in element[1], by doing

```
for item in element[1]:
    print(item)
```

Output is :

```
65.0
zer
```

When you try to do item[0], it's like doing 65.0[0] which is not possible as far as your are subscripting a float, not a list or a tuple.

Try this instead :

```
for item in element[1]:
    print(item)
    temp_list.append(item)
```

Comment: Your assumption isn't correct. Based on my example, it should be `element[1] = [(63.0, "ez"),(65.0, "zer"),(70.0, "oy")]` since I stated `item` is a tuple of (float, string).

Comment: Assumption can be uncorrect, but result is still the same until your error is in your print. Printing item should definitely show you that one of your items is not a tuple as you initially said.